# Натяжка макета (Landing-page) на wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Учусь натягивать верстку на Wordpress на примере лэндинга. У лэндинга несколько блоков со своими классами, для которых происаны свом стили. Я так понял, что эти блоки будут добавляться через `the_post()`, но как wordpress распределяет классы? Потому что в результате свелось к тому, что из 5 блоков у меня остался 1, который состоит из `the_post()`, `the_title()`, `the_content()`. А эти блоки нужно добавлять самому в меню "записи" и через цикл   while выводить в php-документе.

Иными словами у меня такая же проблема, как и https://toster.ru/q/202293. Но тут я не нашел детального ответа, который подошел бы новичку.
Буду благодарен за ссылочку с полезной инфой. Или материал, по которому вы обучались. Просьба не писать "загружай шаблоны и ковыряйся в них".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто вы работаете через основной цикл wordpress если хотите if(post)... Если вы хотите выводить произвольные посты в любых местах надо использовать либо [это](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts), либо [это](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post), ну или [это](http://wp-kama.ru/function/WP_Query). Там же можете поискать как выводить категории